# How do I delete my stupid, "already answered" questions?

Tags: discussion

And yes, I once again looked through the entire list of possible answers and found no answers to my question.

Comment: @JimSmith Can you [edit] this meta post to include a list of questions to which this applies? You need not feel compelled to do so, but you'll probably get more useful answers here if you do. For example, if the problem you asked about can no longer be reproduced and it's *clear* no answer is useful (not even to *others* with similar problems), a question could be closed, which is the usual first step toward deletion. This is not *commonly* done for questions with upvoted answers though, since an upvoted answer is one someone found useful (or at least believed useful).

Answer (score 3):

I presume you mean you want to delete a post on this website that you have since found an answer to?  As far as I know you can't, what you can do however is answer your own question so anyone else who comes across it has a valuable answer.